# CVXPY trying to formulate big problem: ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed. Is RAM usage the problem here?

Tags: cvxpy

I am facing a problem trying to run a fairly large optimization problem in my opinion. You can see the code below. The variable b size is 500 x 96. What I am trying to do is to match a sum of timeseries profiles (351236 x 15 min timesteps) with a bigger profile by minimizing their difference. With the same formulation and a much smaller problem (672 timesteps and a b variable of the size 10 x 5) the problem is solved in under 2 seconds without a problem. But when I am running it for the full scale problem I get the error you see below.

I am running this on Jupyter Lab and python 3.7.4. The python installation is done with conda.

I would expect the problem to solve as with the much smaller problem. But when I run this one, RAM usage explodes up to 100 GB (about 99% of the available RAM on the server). After a while the RAM usage goes down and then a periodical swinging begins (RAM goes up and down from 50% to 100% every few minutes). From the error and after a lot of googling my suspicion is that the problem is too big for the memory and that at some point data is getting broken down to smaller pieces. I do not think it reaches to the point, where the solver does its work. I tried to optimize the code by vectorizing everything (current version) and trying not to have loops etc. in the formulation. But this did not change anything. Do you guys have any clue if this is a bug or a limitation? Or do you maybe have an idea on how to solve this?

```
X_opt = cp.Constant(np.asarray(X.iloc[:,:500])) # the array size is (35136,500)
K_opt = cp.Constant(np.asarray(K.YearlyDemand)) # the vector size is 96
b = cp.Variable((500,96),boolean = True, value = np.zeros((500,96)))
Y_opt = cp.Constant(np.asarray(y)) # the vector size is 35136

constraints = []

constraints.append( cp.sum(b, axis = 0) == 1 ) # the sum of the elements of every column of b must be equal to 1
constraints.append( cp.sum(b, axis = 1) <= 1 ) # the sum of the elements of every row of b must be smaller or equal to 1

objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.abs(Y_opt-cp.sum((cp.diag(K_opt)*((X_opt@b).T)).T, axis = 1))))

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

prob.solve(solver = cp.GLPK_MI, verbose = True)
```

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
in

```
D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py in solve(self, *args, **kwargs)
287 else:
288 solve_func = Problem._solve
--> 289 return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
290
291 @classmethod

D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py in _solve(self, solver, warm_start, verbose, parallel, gp, qcp, **kwargs)
567 self._construct_chains(solver=solver, gp=gp)
568 data, solving_inverse_data = self._solving_chain.apply(
--> 569 self._intermediate_problem)
570 solution = self._solving_chain.solve_via_data(
571 self, data, warm_start, verbose, kwargs)

D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\chain.py in apply(self, problem)
63 inverse_data = []
64 for r in self.reductions:
---> 65 problem, inv = r.apply(problem)
66 inverse_data.append(inv)
67 return problem, inverse_data

D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\matrix_stuffing.py in apply(self, problem)
98 # Batch expressions together, then split apart.
99 expr_list = [arg for c in cons for arg in c.args]
--> 100 Afull, bfull = extractor.affine(expr_list)
101 if 0 not in Afull.shape and 0 not in bfull.shape:
102 Afull = cvxtypes.constant()(Afull)

D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\utilities\coeff_extractor.py in affine(self, expr)
76 size = sum([e.size for e in expr_list])
77 op_list = [e.canonical_form[0] for e in expr_list]
---> 78 V, I, J, b = canonInterface.get_problem_matrix(op_list, self.id_map)
79 A = sp.csr_matrix((V, (I, J)), shape=(size, self.N))
80 return A, b.flatten()

D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\cvxcore\python\canonInterface.py in get_problem_matrix(linOps, id_to_col, constr_offsets)
65
66 # Unpacking
---> 67 V = problemData.getV(len(problemData.V))
68 I = problemData.getI(len(problemData.I))
69 J = problemData.getJ(len(problemData.J))

D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\cvxcore\python\cvxcore.py in getV(self, values)
320
321 def getV(self, values):
--> 322 return _cvxcore.ProblemData_getV(self, values)
323
324 def getI(self, values):

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved here:

https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/826#issuecomment-648618636

Note that the general problem is that large problems create underlying matrixies too large for the numpy.int32 which CVXPY uses. You can modify the code in CVXPY fairly easily to continue using the SCS solver.

You will have to modify the file canonInterface.py here:

D:\Anaconda3\envs\py37DuAL\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\cvxcore\python\

If you have trouble finding the second file to modify, just modify the first one, and use the traceback to find the second file.